# Reading Infomation from either MQTT topic or payload to insert as a string?

Tags: automation, arduino, mqtt, home-automation

I have this code that has been a colaboration with some other fine guys,

here is a like to the github 
[MQTT RELAY DRIVER CODE](https://github.com/Bedrock-Media-Productions/Relay8-Home-Automation-Controller-MQTT/blob/master/RelaydriverMQTT.ino)

the issue we have is in order to have each channel turn on we need to change the value stored here

setLatchChannelOn(2); // with the number being the channelID 1-16,

we construct the MQTT topic like /house/switchboard/12/relay/+/command // + being relay number

any help is appreaciated

```
 // TODO: This should be more generic and awesome

  String tmpBuf = topic;
  Serial.println(tmpBuf);
  Serial.println(String(mqttTopicPrefix).length());
  //if (strcmp(topic, "relay1") == 0) {
  if (true) {
    Serial.println("Matched");
    if ((char)payload[0] == '1')
    {
      setLatchChannelOn(2);
      Serial.println("Relay 2 triggered ON");
      client.publish(mqttStatusTopic, '1');

    }
    else if ((char)payload[0] == '0')
    {
      setLatchChannelOff(2);
      Serial.println("Relay 2 triggered OFF");
      client.publish(mqttStatusTopic, '0');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your question about how to parse MQTT string `relayx` to get `x`? Read [StringstartsWithEndsWith](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringStartsWithEndsWith).

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question ?